# glyphicons-halflings-regular - 404 (NOT FOUND) in Sharepoint Hosted Add-in

Tags: sharepoint-hosted-app, boot-strap

I have developed one SharePoint hosted add-in where in I've used offline bootstrap CSS and glyphicons font. But when I try to load the page it is giving me an error in the browser as below:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)
>       on glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2, glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff and
>   glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf.

Link of glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 found to be like

```
http://apps-d438d5193fcfcb.kblapps.co.in:6415/costingportal/CostingPortalReports/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
```

I tried to resolve this issue with https://stackoverflow.com/a/32300611/2985930 but no luck.

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Its a 404 error which means file is not available at that path. Check the path of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, 404 error states that expected path to file is not found. So, I decompiled the package and looked for the fonts folder. It was not there.

The mistake I made was, instead of creating a module I created a normal folder for font.

And that's it, issue is resolved now. Fonts are included in package.

Thanks anyway.